# Minecraft Server - Performance implications of different Garbage Collectors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

Since my specific question at 
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324833/what-startparameters-to-choose-for-a-modded-minecraft-server?noredirect=1#comment462727_324833 
 got mostly misunderstood, let's boil it down to one question.

What performance implications do the different Garbage Collectors of the JVM have on a Minecraft server with a heap size of 6GB and a multicore processor?
I am looking for current Benchmarks or explanations.

I already read through quite some benchmarks and minecraft optimizations but they are rather old or work only with one thread and less heap size and therefore not applicable to the current scenario

**Things I already read**

- [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40972_01/doc.70/e40973/cnf_jvmgc.htm#autoId2)
- [Minecraft Forum make your server lagg less](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/alpha/alpha-survival-multiplayer/823328-making-your-server-lag-less-by-tuning-java)
- [Allocating RAM for modded client and server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183775/allocating-ram-for-modded-client-and-server)
- [G1 vs CMS vs Parallel GC Benchmark](https://plumbr.io/blog/garbage-collection/g1-vs-cms-vs-parallel-gc)
- [Garbage Collectors - Serial vs. Parallel vs. CMS vs. G1](https://blog.takipi.com/garbage-collectors-serial-vs-parallel-vs-cms-vs-the-g1-and-whats-new-in-java-8/)
- [Difference between -XX:UseParallelGC and -XX:+UseParNewGC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101518/difference-between-xxuseparallelgc-and-xxuseparnewgc)
- [What is the fastest Garbage Collector in Java 8?](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/07/31/WhatIsTheFastestGarbageCollectorInJava8.html)
- [Minecraft Gamepedia Tutorials/Server](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Server_startup_script)
- [Spigot - Useful Arguments to increase Server performance](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/useful-java-arguments-to-increase-server-performance.98374/)

Comment: I think this has more to do with Java than Minecraft. There doesn't seem to be anything specific to gaming here.